# Webpack : config npm modules load

Tags: angularjs, npm, node-modules, vendor, webpack-2

I'm new with webpack and I didn't find a way to load my vendor libs from node_modules with their dependencies (order and main files [js, css]) into a separate bundle file.
I used to work with bower_components but according to [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-bower.html#prefer-modules-from-npm-over-bower) documentation I moved to npm.

## Example

I have angular material in my system that depends on angular and his own css file (angular-material.css).

## What did I try already

I used the **webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin** which did load the venodors js files, but in the order that I entered in the configuration file (see config file attached below) so if I would have put angular material before angular the run would fail.

I tried configuring the resolve object to read from the "bower.json" which has a main files description and dependencies configured in it but that didn't work as well.

## My config file

```
let webpack = require("webpack");
let path = require("path");

// define preprocessor variables
const envOptions = {
NODE_ENV: "development",
  DEBUG: true,
  isProduction: false
};

// pass as JSON object into query string ?json=...
const envJson = require('querystring').encode({json:JSON.stringify(envOptions)});

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: {
    app: "./app.ts",
    vendor: [
        "jquery",
        "angular-animate",
        "angular-aria",
        "angular-messages",
        "angular-resource",
        "angular-sanitize",
        "angular-ui-router",
        "angular-cache",
        "angularjs-toaster",
        "angular-translate",
        "angular-translate-handler-log",
        "angular-translate-loader-static-files",
        "angular-material",
        "angular",
        "angular-dynamic-locale",
        "ng-file-upload",
        "angular-permission",
        "moment",
        "angular-moment",
        "angular-hotkeys",
        "angular-scroll",
        "jquery.scrollbar",
        "lodash",
        "ag-grid",
        "angular-ui-tree"],
   },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts/, loader: ['ts-loader?transpileOnly=true', `ifdef-loader?${envJson}`], exclude: [nodeModulesDir], }
     ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery" : "jquery",
      "moment": "moment",
      "agGrid": "ag-grid"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
     { name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.bundle.js' ,  test: 'node_modules/'}
      )
  ],
  resolve:{
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts','.js', '.css', '.scss'],
  },
  devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

### What do I want to achieve

Webpack will generate 2 bundles:

- **vendor.bundle.js** - a file that contains all the vendor main js
  files in the correct loading order.
- **app.bundle.js** - a file that contains all of my app's inner files.
- **vendor.bundle.css** - a file with all the vender main css files

both vendor bundles should be as defined as in the bower.json dependencies.
My Webpack version is 2.1.0-beta.25

Comment: with webpack.. you dont need to maintain the order, webpack will do that for you based on which ts/module imports which other ts-files/modules

Comment: "I used the webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin which did load the venodors js files, but in the order that I entered in the configuration file (see config file attached below) so if I would have put angular material before angular the run would fail" @entre

Comment: as such angular material would internally be referencing angular, for it compilation purpose, right? so if you reference material.. so got the order in place. your code -> matertial -> angular... so webpack will take care of it